# Determine if First line of MultiLine is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to have a running update list to an item, that is updated from a userform.
I'd like to automatically date any comments / updates to the update when there is a new update, otherwise it should be left alone.

```
    'Check Comments for new update, then add to the comments list with date
If Not Me.Controls("Comments" & i).value = "" Then
        ws.Range("J" & i + 1) = vbCrLf & Format(Now(), "mm/dd") & "-" & Me.Controls("Comments" & i).value
        End If
Next i
```

The issue is that when old updates are inside the box, it will add a new line as if there was a new update like "12/14 - " leaving the rest blank

Is there a way to check if the first character of a text box is empty / first line?

Comment: I should clarify: IF box is NOT empty = Save update in a new line with the date is what the goal is, however it should check if the FIRST line is EMPTY, not the whole box.

Answer (score 0):

- Assumes the line delimiter in the box is `vbCrLf`
- If soft return is used as the line delimiter, change it to `Chr(10)`

```vb
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = Me.Controls("Comments" & i).Value
    If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then
        If Len(Split(sTxt, vbCrLf)(0)) = 0 Then
            ws.Range("J" & i + 1) = vbCrLf & Format(Now(), "mm/dd") & "-" & sTxt
        End If
    End If
```

OR

```vb
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = Me.Controls("Comments" & i).Value
    If Left(sTxt, 2) = vbCrLf Then
        ws.Range("J" & i + 1) = vbCrLf & Format(Now(), "mm/dd") & "-" & sTxt
    End If
```

---

*Update:*

```vb
    Dim sTxt As String
    sTxt = Me.Controls("Comments" & i).Value
    If Len(sTxt) > 0 Then
        ws.Range("J" & i + 1) = vbCrLf & Format(Now(), "mm/dd") & "-" & sTxt _
                & vbCrLf & ws.Range("J" & i + 1)
    End If
```

Comment: I have attempted both ways, and it seems to be failing the Split If Check.
When i try to see what it is doing with "MsgBox Len(Split(sTxt, vbCrLf)(0))" I obtain an error, the If statement alone will run, but not update the boxes when I type in anything.

Comment: May I know what's the value of sTxt? What's kind of newline in your textbox (ie. how uses input a new line)?

Comment: right now, the userform pulls from the sheet and populates the "comment" box.
The user will add any new comment to the box, when it is saved, it is saved to a  new line in the box.
So when the user form is opened again, it will be a new empty line on top, and any old comments below.

Comment: `saved to a new line in the box` do you mean save to cell? Try updated code. Please edit your post to share a screeshot if it is not your exptected. It's helpful to understand your case.